# A morphism to the mapping cone?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

In the second part of the proof for the Proposition 2. in [**Derived Categories** by *Daniel Mufet*](http://therisingsea.org/notes/DerivedCategories.pdf), one finds the following:

> A collection of morphisms $f^n:Q^n\to X^n\oplus Y^{n-1}$ with components $g^n:Q^n\to X^n$ and $\Sigma^n:Q^n\to Y^{n-1}$ defines a morphism of complexes $f:Q\to C_u[-1]$ if and only if $g:Q\to X$ is a morphism of complexes and $\Sigma$ is a homotopy $ug\simeq0,$ and moreover we can recover $g$ as the composite $kf.$

And my question is why is this true?

When I compute the commutative diagram:
$$\begin{matrix}Q^n&\overset{\partial_Q^n}{\to}&Q^{n+1}\\
\downarrow f^n&&\downarrow f^{n+1}\\
C_u[-1]^n&\overset{\partial_u^{n-1}}{\to}&C_u[-1]^{n+1}
\end{matrix},$$
I get the following two relations:
$$\begin{cases}g^{n+1}\circ\partial_Q^n=-\partial_X^n\circ g^n\\
\Sigma^{n+1}\circ\partial_Q^n=u^n\circ g^n+\partial^{n-1}\circ\Sigma^n\end{cases},$$
which differs from my expectations by some negative signs.
Since $g=kf$ is a morphism indeed, I guess I am missing something in the above calculations, but I don't see where I went wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. Here we wre working in an abelian category, $u:X\to Y$ is a morphism, $C_u^n:=X^{n+1}\oplus Y^n$ is the mapping cone of $u,$ and $k$ is the projection $C_u[-1]\to X.$

Answer (score 0):

Now I know where the problem is:
In the definition of $X[n]$ it is stated that the differential is $\partial_{x[n]}^p=(-1)^n\partial_X^{n+p}.$ Hence we actually get the two relations:
$$\begin{cases}g^{n+1}\circ\partial_Q^n=\partial_X^n\circ g^n\\
\Sigma^{n+1}\circ\partial_Q^n=-u^n\circ g^n-\partial_Y^{n-1}\circ\Sigma^n\end{cases},$$
thus we deduce that $g$ is a morphism and $\Sigma$ is a homotopy $0\simeq ug.$